# How to send Parameters (some values) from servlet to android

Tags: android, json

```
on the server side i am doing this and have to send three strings from this class
```

to the client side in android application

```
  @Override
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
      throws ServletException {
        name1 = getParameter(req, "name");
        phone1 = getParameter(req, "phone");
        dob1 = getParameter(req, "dob");
        String regId = getParameter(req, PARAMETER_REG_ID);
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        Datastore.register(regId);
        Datastore.register_name(name1);
        Datastore.registerPhone(phone1);
        Datastore.registerDob(dob1);
}
```

And On The Client Side I have to Recieve it

Actually i was doing it to get responses from server to client it has relay simple solution what you want to send from server to client side if you have post method in the do post method u have to make some output stream and what ever you write on the stream you can get easily by reading that output stream

Comment: Are you sending the request for those strings from the client side Android app?

Comment: i have not used json yet but i think i need to bind it together into json array and then i can send it to the android app that is client side so just want some idea that how can i do this

Comment: if you are sending the request for those strings from the android app means, as you have mentioned use json array and jsonObjects to hold those strings. return it back as server response and continue in client side by parsing it. if you directly want to send something from server then the below answer from varun verma might help you. I have no experience with that.

Answer (score 1):

yes u can use this way on servlet response

```
resp.setHeader(java.lang.String name, java.lang.String value)
```

and at Android end you can get the value from response

```
    String value =response.getHeaders(name);
```

I hope u will get into the way i told u .....

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear ... 
Please edit your question and explain in detail

What I have understood is: You want to send some messages / parameters from your back end Server to the Mobile device.

If this is what you need, then have a look at the Google Cloud Messaging : http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html which is designed specifically for this.